# Amazon dynamodb record size limit work around

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am developing an application that stores questions that people has answered in a nosql database. I am using AWS dynamodb but the record size limit is 400 kb. How would I store more than 400kb of data. Would it be best to put a reference to the next record in the current record? If anyone has any other thoughts or ideas it would be great.

Comment: What sort of data are you trying to save in Dynamodb? I mean are you trying to keep any binary data (i.e. file attachments) or usual String, Numeric data?

Comment: its all going to be strings right now. I am basically developing a survey website. so I do not know how many questions there would be.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of storing all the answers for a user in a single item you can store each answer as a single item. For e.g let say the questions belong to a survey then your table schema looks like this:

SurveyId(Hash Key) | User(Hash key) | Question(Range Key) | Answer.

So if a survey contains n answers for a user there will be n items in dynamoDb table. To find list of all answers for a user we can query on hashkey(surveyId + User). A similar use case is discussed [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForItems.html#GuidelinesForItems.OneToMany)  .

Depending on how frequently we exceed the maximum record size we can store large items to s3.

Regards
Dinesh Solanki

Comment: wouldnt that take longer to pull all the questions and answers. I was thinking of surveyID | userID | array with questions and answers . THen if it more than the record limit split it into n records with references to the next node.

Comment: DynamoDb stores rows with same HashKey on same partition, so only a single partition is involved in returning query result. Also since you don't need to filter results the performance shouldn't be a concern, the performance of Query operation is discussed here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#ScanQueryPerformance. 
Splitting into n records and maintaining consistency/atomicity among operations doesn't look like an easy problem. How will you measure & decide to split? What additional information you will add to convey there are  additional rows.

Answer (score 1):

Current best practices are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-use-s3-too.html

They have two suggestions:

1. compress the data and use the binary datatype
2. store the data in S3

Given #1 would still make you run into a data entry limit at some point, I'd suggest #2